# footer at the bottom in mobile

Tags: css, position, footer

I want to make my footer to always be at the bottom of my page but I am having a hard time with it.

I tried to position it absolute with a bottom margin of 0, and also tried the same with a fixed position but both were not results I was happy with.

the absolute one didn't change anything,

and I didn't like how the fixed position showed the footer at all times.

is there another way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you! Kas

```css
#footer{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}

#details{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  gap:10px;
}
```

```html
<h5>Footer Example<h5>
<footer id = 'footer'>
  <ul id = 'details'>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li>Address</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Logo</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```